# How do I make an A.I. reward system?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

This question is because I think it would be fun to make an A.I.

Any programming language is acceptable. I am wondering how do I make a simple program that can associate certain things with points and learn to prefer things with more points associated with them. It is a very general question.

If you need an example, how would I make a program that can retrieve an input like "hello" and then search through a list of appropriate responses and choose the response that currently has the most "points" and then the user (me) can add points or take away points from that association in the console?

I know how to code already I just don't understand how the process would work. You don't even need to give me any code I am just asking about how this procedure would work? Sorry if the post is worded poorly I have autism and can't communicate effectively sometimes lol.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) is what you're looking for.

> Reinforcement learning (RL) is an area of machine learning concerned with how intelligent agents ought to take actions in an environment in order to maximize the notion of cumulative reward.

As for code examples, [this collection of algorithm implementations on GitHub](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning) may serve as a reference.

In general, an "agent" takes an "action" based on the current "state" of an environment to change it, calculates a "reward" based on the action taken and observed change in state, and works to optimize the reward gained.